# Is juxt the opposite of map? (In Clojure)

Tags: dictionary, clojure, higher-order-functions

In Clojure we see the following examples of using [`map`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/map):

```
(map inc [1 2 3 4 5])
;;=> (2 3 4 5 6)
```

We observe that `map` takes a function and applies it to each element in a collection.

In Clojure we see the following example of using [`juxt`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/juxt):

```
((juxt inc dec) 2)
;=>[3 1]
```

We observe that `juxt` takes a data structure and applies each function to it.

My question is: **Is juxt the opposite of map?** 
(In that you *map* a data structure over a collection of functions instead of the other way around)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can call juxt the opposite of map. Juxt composes a number of functions into one function that produces a sequence of the result of applying each of the functions to its argument(s).

Answer (score 0):

I guess `juxt` could be (should be?) expressed using a `map` 
    (defn juxt [& funs] (fn [& args] (map #(apply % args)) funs))